# javascript - setTimeout return

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

How can I use setTimeout if I want to return a value

```
$.each(pCodes, function(index, pCode) {
    setTimeout(func(parm1), 2000);      
});


function func(in)
{
  var value = 999;
  return value;
}
```

Comment: How would you use this return value? It doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: To what do you want to return that value? You have no idea what will be running when the timeout happens.

Comment: I want to call function func every 2 seconds and return a value on each call.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  What do you want to return the value _to_?

Comment: But return a value *to where*. See my answer for the pattern that is generally used for 'returning' a value from a timeout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, your call to `setTimeout` is wrong. You are calling the function `func` and then using the result in the `setTimeout` method. Your code is equivalent to:

```
$.each(pCodes, function(index, pCode) {
  var temp = func(parm1);
  setTimeout(temp, 2000);      
});
```

As `func` returns `999`, you will be doing `setTimeout(999, 2000)`, which of course doesn't make sense. To call a function that takes a parameter from `setTimeout` you need a function that makes that function call:

```
$.each(pCodes, function(index, pCode) {
  setTimeout(function() { func(parm1); }, 2000);
});
```

To handle the return value from `func` is a bit more complicated. As it's called later on, you have to handle the return value later on. Usually that is done with a callback method that is called when the return value is available:

```
var callback = function(value) {
  // Here you can use the value.
};
$.each(pCodes, function(index, pCode) {
  setTimeout(function() { func(parm1, callback); }, 2000);
});

function func(in, callback) {
  var value = 999;
  callback(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make sure you pass to `setTimeout` a function, in your example you passed `undefined` to it, as you `func(param1)` executes `func` directly. What you want is something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { func(parm1); }, 2000);
```

And for 'returning' the value: Use some kind of callback function that is executed with the value when timeout expired. Like so:

```
function callback(value) {
  //  doSomethingWithNewValue
}

$.each(pCodes, function(index, pCode) {
    setTimeout(function() { func(parm1, callback); }, 2000);      
});


function func(in, callback)
{
  var value = 999;
  callback(value);
}
```

This is the general pattern used in such scenario (see [event driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming)).

Comment: The idea is good and correct but  `setTimeout(func(parm1, callback), 2000);` is wrong as it will get evaluated immediatly. You want to do something like `setTimeout(function(){func(parm1, callback);}, 2000);`

Comment: When you call func(parm1, callback), is callback a variable or the name of the function?

Answer (score 0):

change it to :

```
var defValue;

$.each(pCodes, function(index, pCode) {
    setTimeout(function(){defValue=func(parm1)}, 2000);      
});
```

this way you can use the defValue in your function to access the returned value

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty ugly, but you can use output parameters, since js objects are pass by reference:

```
function a() {
    var param1 = 42;
    var result = {};
    b(param1, result);
}

function b(val, output) {
    something();
    output.returned = 4;
}
```

Or, you can use a callback (the better option):

```
function a() {
    var param1 = 42;
    b(param1, function (newVal) {
        something();
    });
}

function b(val, callback) {
    //something
    callback(4);
}
```

By the way, your call to setTimeout is wrong. setTimeout receives a function as a first parameter, and a delay as a second - the first argument is still seen as regular javascript code, so it evaluates it, so your setTimeout call turns out to be like this:

```
setTimeout(999, 2000);
```

Since you're returning 999 from the function.

However, setTimeout can also receive a list of arguments after the second parameter, so it can be turned into this:

```
setTimeout(func, 2000, param1);
```