# Try a Function Multiple Times on Timeout, Return on Success or when Maximum Tries Passed

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm wondering if it is possible in Javascript to call a function up to a number of N times to get a truthy value back. It should immediately return if the return is `true`. It should at least return regardless of the return value after N times.

I read a bit through existing resources and came to the point that it is *not* possible, but normally done with a callback function. Are there any patterns / best practices / examples for that?

Comment: Reference: [javascript - setTimeout return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142010/javascript-settimeout-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following implementation:

```
multitry = function(time, tries, func, callback) {
    counter = 0;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        ((success = func(++counter)) || (counter >= tries))
            && !clearInterval(timer) 
            && callback(success, counter)      
        ;
    }, time);
};
```

For example to try 30 times each 250 milliseconds if the tag-editing has been enabled, you can run the following:

```
javascript:(function(){
    multitry = function(time, tries, func, callback) {
        counter  = 0;
        timer    = setInterval(function() {
            counter++;
            var value = func(counter);
            if (value || counter >= tries) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                callback(value, counter);
            }
        }, time);
    };
    multitry(
        250, 
        30, 
        function() {
            return $('#tagnames').length;
        }, 
        function (success) {
            console.log('Tag editor did open:', success);
        }
    );
}());
```

Comment: Oh dear god. Just use an if statement. There's no reason to tie things together with boolean operators like that unless you're goal is to intentionally make your code unreadable...

Comment: I personally do not find that unreadable (well the semicolon could help more placed elsewhere), but true, you can wrap that inside an if statement if you prefer.

Comment: @ircmaxell: I edited the second example with an if clause, but it's not really getting more readable in my eyes.

Comment: @ircmaxell: success value is missing, it's needed so that in the callback it's clear if there was success or not. I also thought about not using variables, however then the names are a bit lost.