# Why doesn't setTimeout work as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtmlx

I am trying to move a `<div id="box">` each time my mouse pointer hovers over it, but it appears to move only when I have the `mouseover` event on the div and not when my mouse hovers over it.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("load",init());

function init(){
 console.log('in init');
 document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
    var pixels=5;
    var perMs=40;
    var repeater=setTimeout(moveBox(pixels),perMs);

    document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
        console.log('mouseOut');
        clearTimeout(repeater);
        });

    });

 }

 function moveBox(pixels){

    console.log('moveBox');
    var leftBox=document.getElementById("box").style.left;
    leftBox=parseInt(leftBox)+pixels;
    document.getElementById("box").style.left=leftBox;

  }
```

Comment: `.addEventListener("load",init);`  You want to pass the function itself, not run it and pass its return value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript - setTimeout return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142010/javascript-settimeout-return)

Comment: I tried passing the function like this document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("load",function ()  

but still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though you meant to use `setInterval` instead, to adjust the element on a repeated basis:

```
var repeaterId = setInterval(moveBox, perMs, pixels);
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Comment: it does work now it was about how I pass the parameters tho the same funtion call like setInterval(moveBox(pixel),perMs)  didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) recieves a callback function as a first parameter, problem is that moveBox(pixels) executes the function and returns it's result so you should wrap it into another function.

Also you would want to unsubscribe from the 'mouseout' event every time you subscribe to it in your mouseover callback:

```
function init(){
 console.log('in init');
 document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
    var pixels=5;
    var perMs=40;
    var repeater=setTimeout(function(){moveBox(pixels)},perMs);



    document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("mouseout",function onMouseOut(){
        console.log('mouseOut');
        clearTimeout(repeater);
        document.getElementById("box").removeEventListener("mouseout",onMouseOut);
        });

    });


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many syntax issues in your code, here it is with the major issues corrected.

```
function init() {
    console.log('in init');
    var box = document.getElementById("box"),
        pixels = 5,
        perMs = 40,
        repeater;

    function moveBox(pixels) {
        console.log('moveBox', pixels);
        var boxLeft = parseInt(box.style.left, 10) || 0;
        box.style.left = (boxLeft + pixels) + 'px';
    }

    box.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        repeater = setTimeout(moveBox, perMs, pixels);
    });

    box.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        console.log('mouseOut');
        clearTimeout(repeater);
    });

}

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("load",init);
```

Please note that `setTimeout` is only called once, it doesn't repeat.

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/vqgesj58/1/

If you want your box to move while your mouse is over it, I'll update the code.

Comment: still same problem dude :(

Comment: I updated the code, it should now work as expected for `setTimeout`